# Dynamically generating Firefox toobar content in multiple windows

Tags: firefox-addon

I have a strange one.  I want to generate the dynamically content of a menupopup attached to a toolbar.  This works perfectly if I bring up only one window.  If I bring up more than one, and click on the menupopup in the second, it won't then popup in the first.  If I bring up the popup in the first window first, it works there and in the second.  Here's my overlay code:

```
<toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
    <toolbarbutton
        id="personaswitcher-button"
        label="&personaswitcher-button.label;"
        tooltiptext="&personaswitcher-button.tooltip;"
        type="menu">
        <menupopup
            id="personaswitcher-addon"
            onpopupshowing="PersonaSwitcher.buttonPopup (event);"
            onpopuphidden="PersonaSwitcher.hideSubMenu();"
        />
    </toolbarbutton>
</toolbarpalette>
```

I can see the "PersonaSwitcher.buttonPopup" method being called in all windows.  It dynamically generates the menupopup and menuitems, seemingly without issues.  Does anyone know what might be wrong or where I can look?  Thanks much!

Comment: are you having this issue in australis? im no so sure about this overlay i dont do overlays too much, i can give you a bootstrap solution though would you like to see?

Comment: No, not using Australis.  At this point, I'm stumped, so anything anyone can provide is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: A little more data. In a good window:
    state=showing and
    anchorNode=[object XULElement]
and the innerHTML is set.  In a bad window:
    state=closed and
    anchorNode=null
 Hmm.

Comment: I've now added calling the menupopup creation method when the first window is created.  This seems to work, but I'm not sure it's the best approach...

Answer (score 0):

can you post the code for `buttonPopup()` .....
if you are using `appendChild()` try using `cloneNode()` with it, does that help?

Comment: In [https://github.com/drsjb80/personaswitcher/blob/master/chrome/content/overlay.js](https://github.com/drsjb80/personaswitcher/blob/master/chrome/content/overlay.js) buttonPopup calls createMenuPopup which then creates new menuitem's, so I'm not sure cloneNode would help, but I can try. My current workaround is to create the menupopup when the very first window is created, but I'm not sure that's the cleanest approach.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hey man I can't find anything with ID of BrowserToolbarPalette so i used #nav-bar instead

Open up scratchpad set environment to Browser and paste this and run it, it works fine.

```
var me = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow(null);
var navBar = document.querySelector('#nav-bar');

var myToolBarButton = document.createElement('toolbarbutton');
var props = {
    id: 'personaswitcher-button',
    label: 'personaswitcher-button.label;',
    tooltiptext: 'personaswitcher-button.tooltip',
    type: 'menu'
}
for (var p in props) {
    myToolBarButton.setAttribute(p, props[p]);
}

var menuPopup = document.createElement('menupopup');
var props = {
    id: 'personaswithcer-addon',
    onpopupshowing: 'PersonaSwitcher.buttonPopup (event);',
    onpopuphidden: 'PersonaSwitcher.hideSubMenu();'
}
for (var p in props) {
    menuPopup.setAttribute(p, props[p]);
}

var myMenuItem = document.createElement('menuitem');
myMenuItem.setAttribute('label','a menu item');

menuPopup.appendChild(myMenuItem);
myToolBarButton.appendChild(menuPopup);
navBar.appendChild(myToolBarButton);
```

so if the above works, trying changing your overlay to this:

```
<toolbar id="nav-bar">
    <toolbarbutton
        id="personaswitcher-button"
        label="&personaswitcher-button.label;"
        tooltiptext="&personaswitcher-button.tooltip;"
        type="menu">
        <menupopup
            id="personaswitcher-addon"
            onpopupshowing="PersonaSwitcher.buttonPopup (event);"
            onpopuphidden="PersonaSwitcher.hideSubMenu();"
        />
    </toolbarbutton>
</toolbarpalette>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! BrowserToolbarPalette comes from looking at [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Toolbars/Creating_toolbar_buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Toolbars/Creating_toolbar_buttons) and I set it up in chrome/content/overlay-fx.xul. After switching creating the menus on the first window, they were showing up every other window. So now I'm creating them in all windows onload, and it works as I would expect. Thanks again!

Comment: Cool man I didn't know if it would help :) I think you can still do overlay just probably abandon BorwserToolbarPalette that link is a dead link